# Ruby - Remove The String?

Tags: ruby, string, algorithm

**Question** :Given two strings X and Y, 
find the minimum number of characters to be removed from X in order to obtain a string X' that does not contain Y as a substring.

*Input*: ababba aba

*EXPECTED output*: 1 (output exactly one integer is the minimum number of characters to be remove)

**My code** i have simply done whether string is present or not

```
str1 = gets.chomp
str2 = gets.chomp
if str1.include? str2
  puts "yup"
else
  puts "no"
end
```

Comment: `puts "i'm getting the Internet to do my homework"` ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight forward solution without efficiency concern:

```
def remove_count(x, y)
  index = x.index(y)
  if index.nil?
    0
  else
    removes = []
    index.upto(index + y.length - 1) do |i|
      r = remove_count(x[0, i] + x[(i+1)..-1], y)
      if r == 0
        return 1
      else
        removes << r
      end
    end
    removes.min + 1
  end
end

puts remove_count('ababba', 'aba')
puts remove_count('aaaaaa', 'aa')
```

BTW: I'm interested for the efficient solutions. I think this should be tagged with `algorithm`.